# math.h's fmod function giving error when compiling in "C"

Tags: c, gcc

## The Problem

I am learning C and I ran into a problem where I have to find the remainder of two `double`  numbers. But when compiling, the compiler is throwing an error. The following code was from [this site](https://www.techonthenet.com/c_language/standard_library_functions/math_h/fmod.php). I didn't make any changes to it, just copied it and pasted it in a file called `floatMod.c` and compiled the file with `gcc floatMod.c` and it didn't get compiled and I got an error. Since I heard that `-ansi` with compiler command will compile it with legacy version of C, I even tried this `gcc -ansi  floatMod.c`, `cc floadMod.c` and `cc -ansi floadMod.c`. None of these commands worked and I got the same<sup>1</sup> error on each of these commands.

### The code

```
/* Example using fmod by TechOnTheNet.com */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    /* Define temporary variables */
    double value1, value2;
    double result;

    /* Assign the values we will find the fmod of */
    value1 = 1.6;
    value2 = 1.2;

    /* Calculate the remainder of value1 / value2 */
    result = fmod(value1, value2);

    /* Display the result of the calculation */
    printf("The fmod of %f and %f is %f\n", value1, value2, result);

    return 0;
}
```

### The error

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccb72toe.o: in function `main':
floatMod.c:(.text+0x40): undefined reference to `fmod'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

same<sup>1</sup>: In the error's first line, `` /tmp/ccb72toe.o: in function `main': ``, it is just `/tmp/blahblah.o`, where the `blahblah` part is random each time the file is compiled.

### The Machine

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS Desktop
Linux Kernel Version: 5.8.0-59-generic
GCC Version: gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0

Comment: Do you have `-lm` to link the math library in your compile command?

Comment: Does this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209721/gcc-gives-error-while-using-fmod answer your question?

Comment: @y_159 Yeah, it does. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Note that that is a linker error, not a compiler error.  Understanding that makes the issue a build issue, not a code issue.  In GCC you have to explicitly link the math library (libm) is it is separate form the rest of the standard library (libc).